# Irssi freezes after I've added sound notifications

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, notification, irssi

I type `irssi` in the terminal and get in to the program without no problem, but after I have written `/connect` in there and the beep sound I've added using 
in Irssi:

```
/set bell_beeps
/set beep_msg_level MSGS DCC DCCMSGS HILIGHT NOTICES
/set beep_cmd play -q ~/.irssi/scripts/beep_beep.wav 
/save
```

when I try  to change nick I can hear the beep or ding dong sound but I added an MSN notify sound instead of the *http://www.andrews-corner.org/tmp/din...* so I must have done it correct? Then I get this error saying

> [(status)] play WARN alsa: can't encode 0-bit Unknown or not
>   applicable

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, if I put the `-t alsa` at the end, everything works fine ([source](https://github.com/floere/playa/issues/6#issuecomment-1414212093)):

```
play -q "/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga" -t alsa
```